# Invalid constant value with flutter when trying to use Container as variable in Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter and i'm don't understand why i can't do that.
Here is the code I try to compile :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Column child = Column(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Text('Deliver features faster'),
        Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
        Expanded(
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FlutterLogo(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    Widget container = Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(125, 70, 151, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 157, 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: child);


    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(6, 24, 46, 1),
      body: container,
    );
  }
```

AndroidStudio tells me "invalid constant value" on container variable when i try to put it on the scaffold's body field.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I try to play with the const keyword but nothing changed.

Comment: Rohan's answer is correct (you should mark it as accepted if it fixed your problem), but as a general explanation, putting `const` before a constructor (like a widget) is only possible if that constructor is declared as `const`, and everything passed into it is `const`. It's recursive like that. Your `Scaffold` and everything inside may have been const, but when you added the `Container`, which _isn't_ `const`, the `Scaffold` can no longer be `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to remove const before `Scaffold()`

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(6, 24, 46, 1),
      body: container,
    );
```

Comment: Ok thank you why is that I must say it's kind of obscure ^^

Comment: The Container doesn't have a const constructor, therefor you can't make the Scaffold const.